# How does react detect changes in state/props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

JavaScript basically doesn't provide watchers for variables. 
So I wonder how React.js does it.

I'm trying to do the same thing. For objects and arrays, I can use Proxy, like this:

```
let proxy = new Proxy(arr, {
    deleteProperty: function(target, property) {
        console.log("Deleted %s", property);
        return true;
    },
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
        target[property] = value;
        console.log("Set %s to %o", property, value);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Maybe it's not a good idea. And I'm still don't know what to do with literals such as Numbers.

Comment: It doesn't, thats why you have to call `setState`.

Comment: @tkausl, and what about props?

Comment: This sounds like a XY problem, could you maybe elaborate on what your overall goal is?

Comment: @tobias-tengler, I only want to console.log() when an object, array or literal changed

Comment: There isn't really a feature like this for javascript and I couldn't think of a scenario, where it would be useful. You might look into [Object.observe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) and [Object.watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch), but both are deprecated and not supported in all major browsers.

Comment: @tkausl, and what happens when you invoke `setState`, how does it work in depth. I'm trying to understand this thing.

Comment: @TobiasTengler, thanks for the comment. As I said in the question description, with objects I can use Proxy. With Proxy I should write to much code, but at least it works. But what I can do with literals? I have no idea. But React js is able to it. So there is a solution.

Comment: @GregoryOrloff As mentioned reactjs is not watching your variables it (just speculating) shallowly compares the new state you pass into `setState` with the previous state and triggers a component re-render if the state updated. Maybe you should look into the source code of react, since I don't assume anyone here will have the time to explain the `setState` method to you in-depth...

Comment: Explaining the details of React is much too broad for a StackOverflow question. You're better off looking into their source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TL/DR was already given in the comments: React does not watch the data, changes are always triggered from "the outside", which means `setState`. The state does not even have to change, calling `setState` with the same data again already triggers the lifecycle of the component.

However, if you use redux or some other state container, it can look as if components magically detect changes themself whenever the data used by  `mapStateToProps` function changes. But react-redux's `connect` function merely wraps your component with a proxy that listens for events:

- register a listener for every redux action
- compare the current and previous state on every event using strict equal (===)
- if the state is different, call `mapStateToProps`
- compare the result of `mapStateToProps` with previous calls using strict equal
- if different, trigger a rerendering of the component

In order to imitate the behaviour, you would need some kind "thingsDidChange" listener which is triggered by events or continuous (setInterval) check.